# Change color at a touch, script

Tags: c#, unityscript

Hi I got this script from Sebastian's tutorial in youtube, it change the color of a cube at the user touch. I need 5 cubes if one of then is touched all cubes change the same color. Any help is welcome.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
public class TouchInput : MonoBehaviour {

public LayerMask touchInputMask;

private List<GameObject> touchList = new List<GameObject>();
private GameObject[] touchesOld;
private RaycastHit hit;


void Update () {


    if (Input.touchCount > 0){

        touchesOld = new GameObject[touchList.Count];
        touchList.CopyTo(touchesOld);
        touchList.Clear();

        foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches) {

            Ray ray = camera.ScreenPointToRay(touch.position);      

            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit,touchInputMask)) {

                GameObject recipient = hit.transform.gameObject;
                touchList.Add(recipient);

                if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began) {
                    recipient.SendMessage("OnTouchDown",hit.point,SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
                }
                if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended) {
                    recipient.SendMessage("OnTouchUp",hit.point,SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
                }
                if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Stationary) {
                    recipient.SendMessage("OnTouchStay",hit.point,SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
                }
                if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Canceled) {
                    recipient.SendMessage("OnTouchExit",hit.point,SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
                }

            }

        }
        foreach (GameObject g in touchesOld) {
            if (!touchList.Contains(g)) {
                g.SendMessage("OnTouchExit",hit.point,SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
            }
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the code where the color is actually changed.

Comment: Also a non-code (or very limited code depending on how that color change is implemented) approach is sharing the same material between all the cubes. If the code changes the material property, have it change the sharedMaterial property instead, and all the cubes will change color.